# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_flat_index'

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

I am importing an HTML file. It has the data in a weird format and with multi index.

[image]

I am particularly interested in importing the table 'Photovoltaic' and it starts at line 10 in the big table. The table seems to be of multiindex.

code:

```
    net_met_cus = 'https://www.eia.gov/electricity/annual/html/epa_04_10.html'
    
    net_met = pd.read_html(net_met_cus)
    print(len(net_met))
    net_met_pv = net_met[1]
    # Photovoltaic table starts at 12 row
    print(net_met_pv.loc[12])
Unnamed: 0_level_0  Year              Photovoltaic
Capacity (MW)       Residential       Photovoltaic
                    Commercial        Photovoltaic
                    Industrial        Photovoltaic
                    Transportation    Photovoltaic
                    Total             Photovoltaic
Customers           Residential       Photovoltaic
                    Commercial        Photovoltaic
                    Industrial        Photovoltaic
                    Transportation    Photovoltaic
                    Total             Photovoltaic
Name: 12, dtype: object
    # Is it multiindex
    print(net_met_pv.loc[12].index)
MultiIndex([('Unnamed: 0_level_0',           'Year'),
            (     'Capacity (MW)',    'Residential'),
            (     'Capacity (MW)',     'Commercial'),
            (     'Capacity (MW)',     'Industrial'),
            (     'Capacity (MW)', 'Transportation'),
            (     'Capacity (MW)',          'Total'),
            (         'Customers',    'Residential'),
            (         'Customers',     'Commercial'),
            (         'Customers',     'Industrial'),
            (         'Customers', 'Transportation'),
            (         'Customers',          'Total')],
           )
    # Okay, let's flaten it
    net_met_pv.to_flat_index()
```

Present output:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_flat_index'
```

Comment: What is the output of `type(net_met_pv)` ?

Comment: @LidorEliyahuShelef `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

Comment: Does the answer @Trenomarcus supply solves your issue or not?

Comment: After some work around I got it to dataframe by `pv_df = pd.DataFrame(net_met_pv.iloc[13:24].values,
                     columns =pv_cols)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.to_flat_index()` is a method of `Index` or `Multindex`, so you should call using `net_met_pv.loc[12].index.to_flat_index()` or similar calls.

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_flat_index.html?highlight=to_flat_index#pandas.Index.to_flat_index
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_flat_index.html?highlight=to_flat_index#pandas.MultiIndex.to_flat_index